# What actually is precisely a bloodline?

Tags: meaning

It is said that Bloodline means family, and from my research it specifically indicates a dog family more commonly.

My question is why do they not say dog family/family instead of "bloodline" it sounds awkward anyway? or am I missing the precise definition?

I also have seen bloodline meaning the last person in the family, I don't know if I am confusing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Bloodline" is an idiomatic way to refer to someone's family history.

In this case, "blood" is used to refer indirectly to genetic heritage (although the term predates the discovery of genetics).  We can talk about being *"related by blood"* to someone as compared with *"related by marriage"*.   We might say some person's talent is *"in his blood"* to mean that others in his family have similar talents.

You child can be referred to as *"your own flesh and blood"* (although this can also apply to other relatives).

Another expression is *"blood is thicker than water"*, meaning to have stronger obligations to family than to friends or strangers.

If someone has an older relative who has some character trait (usually a bad one), and people suspect they have it as well, they might say, *"blood will tell"* (or *"blood will out"*).  This implies that the trait "runs in the family" and will eventually express itself.

As in your example, "bloodline" can also refer to animals, particularly those with a ["pedigree"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pedigree) who may have been bred for generations to reinforce certain traits.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with the last person in the family or a royal family, right? It's only blood related individuals family, am I correct?

Comment: really it refers to **everyone** born in the family  including the last person.

Comment: It refers to a *lineage*, so yes, not just an individual. You can talk about a "royal bloodline", which could include everyone related to the royal family.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt, the definition is exactly what I thought. :3

Answer (score 1):

> blood·line
>
> noun
>
> an animal's set of ancestors or pedigree, typically considered with
>   regard to the desirable characteristics bred into it. a set of
>   ancestors or line of descent of a person. Google dictionary

While it is common to use this in discussion of a horse's or dog's lineage, it can also be used to discuss human ancestry.

> There was hemophilia in the queen's bloodline and the prince died at
>   an early age from the disease.